# Weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.soapfault.WLSOAPFaultException: Old Format Work Area Header Is Disabled Exception Post WebLogic Upgrade

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

After the upgrade of weblogic to newer version I started facing an error with different application conectivity.

```
RequestDumpingFilter Response; Content=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><StatusBadGateway xmlns="http://types.xxx"><BackendSystem>Infomatica</BackendSystem><BackendServiceCall>getUsage</BackendServiceCall><ErrorMessage>RuntimeException when calling getUsage. javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Old format work area header is disabled.</ErrorMessage></StatusBadGateway>
```

Does anyone knows the solution? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is caused due to old headers in use even after upgrade, no common soap header format is in use. See below.

**APPLIES TO:**
Oracle WebLogic Server - Version 12.2.1.0.0 and later
Information in this document applies to any platform.

**SYMPTOMS**
WebLogic has recently been upgraded to WebLogic 12.2.1.2 from 9.2. Post upgrade, the webservice request is not working with
below header format exception.

```
Jun 12, 2017 7:04:03 AM CDT> - [Error in invoking service : java.rmi.RemoteException:
SOAPFaultException - FaultCode [{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server] FaultString [Old
format work area header is disabled.
] FaultActor [null] Detail [javax.xml.rpc.JAXRPCException: Old format work area header is disabled.
]; nested exception is:
weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.soapfault.WLSOAPFaultException: Old format work area header is disabled.
```

**SOLUTION**
Make sure common same SOAP header format is in use between webservice communications, else disable the work area header
validation using the flag below:

```
 -Dweblogic.wsee.workarea.skipWorkAreaHeader=true
```